# Will looking at the sun make you blind?

Tags: ophthalmology, sun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does staring at the sun cause significant, permanent harm?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/570/does-staring-at-the-sun-cause-significant-permanent-harm)

As a child I was told to never look directly at the sun because it can make you blind.

However:

- I have never heard of cases where somebody got blind *this* way.
- Often enough I have looked into the sun myself directly without noticeable consequences.

I am aware that an injury of blindness does not hurt and that blindness will only start in a little spot of the eye as the light is focuses on the retina.

My thoughts: Unlike a laser beam, the light of the sun which reaches the eye is not coherent and not as powerful.

Comment: I'm sure you'll soon get asked, so I'll tell you: You should post claims that state that looking at the sun can make you blind, check the meta for more information. :)

Comment: @Alenanno I assume you mean the FAQ - not meta, right? Well, I figured this was a common 'knowledge'. But if my question does not meet the FAQ standards, ok. :(

Comment: The FAQ is posted on Meta. Your question was fine, it just had already been answered on this site before. [Here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) is our policy on notability.

Comment: @gentmatt: Also the FAQ yes, but I also meant the Meta, there you can find some topics about the references, claims and the like. :) But I see there was a similar question to yours.

Comment: @SamIAm Touché! I somehow overlooked this :) Thanks.